# GridView ItemTemplate Full Width

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

My question is: how can I stretch the DataTemplate to the full width of the screen. I've tried many solutions but they does not work. 
I've tried `HorizontalContentAlignment`, setting `GridView.ItemContainerStyle` and etc. But nothing works. Can anybody explain me how can I do this?

Here is part of my code:

```
<Grid Style="{StaticResource GeneralAppBackground}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Pivot x:Name="AccountInfoOptions" Grid.Row="1">
        <PivotItem Header="История">
            <GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind CheckoutList}" Margin="5,0,5,0">
                <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:UserCheckout">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="White" Padding="5" Margin="0,5,0,0">
                            <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,10,0">
                                <TextBlock FontSize="14" Text="{x:Bind CheckoutDate}" Foreground="#979797" />
                                <TextBlock FontSize="14" Text="{x:Bind CheckoutTime}" Foreground="#979797" />
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind CheckoutSum}" FontSize="22" FontWeight="Bold" />
                                    <Image Source="/Assets/TengeIcon.png" Width="20" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind CheckoutTitle}" TextAlignment="Center" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemTemplate>

                <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                    </Style>
                </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
            </GridView>
        </PivotItem>
   </Pivot>
```

Comment: All your attempts were unsuccessful because you use StackPanel in Template of GridView. Change To Grid. Grid take all available space, StackPanel - how much does it need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to making it work, is changing the `ItemsPanelTemplate`. Define it as a page resource:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ItemsPanelTemplate">
        <ItemsStackPanel />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
```

Now set it as the `ItemsPanel` for your `GridView`:

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind CheckoutList}" 
          Margin="5,0,5,0" 
          ItemsPanel="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ItemsPanelTemplate}">
```

This will allow individual items to stretch across the full width. You will still need to replace the root `StackPanel` in your `DataTemplate` with a `Grid` as Nikita suggested:

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="local:UserCheckout">
    <Grid BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="White" Padding="5" Margin="0,5,0,0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,10,0">
            <TextBlock FontSize="14" Text="{x:Bind CheckoutDate}" Foreground="#979797" />
            <TextBlock FontSize="14" Text="{x:Bind CheckoutTime}" Foreground="#979797" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind CheckoutSum}" FontSize="22" FontWeight="Bold" />
                <Image Source="/Assets/TengeIcon.png" Width="20" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind CheckoutTitle}" TextAlignment="Center" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

You already have the `Grid.Column` property set correctly for the inner `StackPanel`s. It seems you were attempting to use a `Grid` there before.

Comment: Finally! If you don't mind could you please elaborate more why we need to set it at the app resource? what the setting does actually?

Comment: @HaikalNashuha The key part is not defining the template as a resource, it's changing the `GridView` `ItemsPanel` template. By default, it's `ItemsWrapGrid`. Here I change it to `ItemsStackPanel`. You can find more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/listview-and-gridview#change-the-layout-of-items).